# Terms to Refer to "Malekind" or "Femalekind"

Tags: grammatical-gender, collective-nouns

I'm looking for some terms or phrases that could be used to refer to all the males or all the females collectively and exclusively. Something like a gender-specific version of "mankind" (which usually refers to all humanity with no regards to gender, to the best of my knowledge).

Something like "malekind" and "femalekind", basically.

**Examples**

"_____ (malekind) had its chances with me; I'm moving on to _____ (femalekind)."

or,

"I may have a PhD in Physics, but I will never be able to understand _____ (femalekind)."

(Although that second example could easily just have "women" filling the blank.)

Comment: Are you writing about science? about religion? Please can you give a sample sentence that shows how you would actually *use* one of these terms?  Just leave a blank where the word would go. It is difficult to answer accurately without a context.

Comment: Is there a reason why OP doesn't want to use *men* or *women*? They  would usually be construed to mean what OP wants, as in "Men are from Mars. Women are from Venus".

Comment: @GrahamNicol, I did consider men and women, but I suppose it somehow felt... not "inclusive" or "sweeping" enough. Kind of like how "humans" doesn't feel as wide as "humankind". Is it just me being incredibly, senselessly picky?

Comment: @chaslyfromUK, the best example I can currently come up with is something like: "_____ (_mankind_) had its chances with me; I'm moving on to _____ (_femalekind_)." Or, "I may have a PhD in Physics, but I will never be able to understand _____ (_femalekind_)." (Although that second example could easily just have "women" filling the blank, indeed.)

Comment: The fair sex is what the women in this world are sometimes referred to. So, uh ... "The Phallicans had their chance with me. I'm moving on to the fair sex." Something like that?

Comment: @Shay Always, always edit the question to clarify. Comments are ephemeral, and may not even be read.

Comment: @ShayHacohen -  Yes, it would be confusing to change the actual **question** because that would invalidate existing answers. However it is certainly acceptable to clarify at any stage.

Answer (score 2):

You could consider using [*Manhood*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/manhood) as it means:

> The men of a country or society regarded collectively: ‘Germany had
>   lost the best of her young manhood’

[*Womanhood*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/womanhood) means:

> Women considered collectively: ‘half of Britain’s womanhood is dress
>   size 14 and over’

[Oxford Online Dictionary]

Comment: This is pretty close to what I've been aiming for, but it sounds slightly off since it doesn't refer to "all females" or "all males", but rather "all females/males of a specific community".

Comment: @ShayHacohen Good luck with what you are aiming for.

Comment: Well, I'm starting to lose hope but I wouldn't have been able to know if such a word exists if I would never have checked, don't you agree? :P Anyway, thanks for the help!

Comment: @ShayHacohen Welcome! And indeed It is difficult to find suitable words.

Answer (score 1):

Consider [**fairer sex**](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/the+fairer+sex) and [**sterner sex**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/pt/defini%C3%A7%C3%A3o/ingl%C3%AAs-americano/the-sterner-sex).

> Humorous or sexist euphemisms for the **female and male genders** dating
>   back to a time when specific qualities were attributed to each gender.

[Definition Of](http://www.definition-of.com/sterner+sex)

> Lawrence Paros,  The Erotic Tongue  (1984): '*Sex* comes from the
>   Latin secare, "to cut or divide," and we first used the word to
>   designate the two major categories of humanity we have come to know
>   and love as male and female. (...) We later used the word *sex* not only
>   for dividing the sexes, but to refer to qualities of being male or
>   female. Over time we assigned specific attributes to each category.
>   These distinctions were dutifully recorded in the esteemed OED, making
>   it all very official. The male was described as "**the better**" and "**the
>   sterner**" sex; the female, as "**the fairer**," "**the gentler**," "**the
>   softer**," and "**the devout**" sex. Women were also called "**the second**"
>   sex. For a period of time between the sixteenth and seventeenth
>   centuries, when people spoke of "the sex," they had women in mind.'

[Definition Of](http://www.definition-of.com/gentler+sex)